# Adding keyczar as a Maven dependencies in NetBeans

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, keyczar

I am trying to add keyczar to my current project and I am following the [instructions](https://code.google.com/p/keyczar/wiki/MavenInstructions) provided on the project's webpage.

However this is not working in NetBeans 8.

I added the following lines in my POM file :

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>KeyCzar</id>
        <url>http://keyczar.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/java/maven/</url>     
    </repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keyczar</groupId>
        <artifactId>keyczar</artifactId>
        <version>0.66</version>
</dependency>
```

I can see the repository in the Services tab but under the KeyCzar node only "No result,processing index..." is shown. Trying to seach for keyczar in Add Dependencies yield no results either.

I know that I could manually add the jar file in my project but I fell that kinda defeat the purpose of using Maven to begin with. And since this is managing encryption I want to be sure that I am not releasing a build using a deprecated version of keyczar.

Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you execute maven from outside of NetBeans (i.e. from the command line) does it work? Are you behind a proxy at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that deleting my NetBeans cache folder fixed the problem. It forced Netbeans to rebuild the Maven repository indexes.